# Machine learning data modeling

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am a beginner in Machine learning. I have seen videos which teaches machine learning. But my questions is How can we model our data.

Mostly we get unstructured data. How can I convert that unstructured data into structured format, The BEST way. So that we can find the most useful information from the data.

Any help w.r.t books or links is very thankful.

Comment: What links did you find on google?

Comment: for data modeling I am not finding any good links or methods

Comment: http://www.deeplearningbook.org/

Answer (score 0):

As a machine learning engineer, You will be responsible for preprocessing your data in a way such that it will be acceptabele. by the model.

There is no best way to do this and moresoo, it depends on what type of data you have such as 1. csv datasets, 2. Text dataset, file(image & audio).

Answer (score 0):

In the real world all the data will not be in a structured form. When we get the data very first thing is find 
1. what is the data is all about.
2. what are the features of it and output of it.
Ex: Dataset to predict the height a person and you have all the below info like from which country, Weight, Gender, Hair color etc.. these are the features we say usually term in Machine learning.
3. Then we need to see how the data features are. Like text data or numerical etc.. We need to pre-process the data before we do any analysis of the data. For Ex: In case you data, a feature is all about a review then you need remove all the special function and corpous your data.
4. You need to understand the way model accepts the data and parameters the model has how can we improve the data.( We can do some feature engineering to improve the models etc..)

There is no hard and fast rule you need to do in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to learn about preprocessing and feature extraction. If you make a model in Python, then libraries like Pandas or Scikit learn are very useful. As a first step try to create sentences like "when x occurs then my output y becomes ...".

Answer (score 0):

Before modeling, the data has to be cleaned. There are several methods to clean the data. Go through the link on how to convert data from unstructured data to structured data.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-unstructured-data-to-structured-data-using-python/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33503041)